# How can I keep birds away from seed onions?

Tags: pests, planting, onions

I've just planted onions in garden and I've found little birds trying to steal the small onions today.

How can I keep birds from stealing the onions?

Comment: How large is your patch of onions?

Comment: 10 foot x 12 foot perhaps...

Answer (score 2):

Try row cloth...great stuff for all kinds of reasons.  If you put up some little hoops or stakes you can keep them under the cloth all season.  Water, air and sunlight go through this very light material.  Great to hold in heat and extend the season at both ends.

If you have root crops, cabbage, broccoli, cauliflower, use row cloth on these guys to prevent pests laying eggs.  The larvae eat the roots.  Do be careful because when the weather gets warm it can be 30 degrees hotter beneath so remove covers during the day.  By the time the weather gets warmer you can leave the covers off as the plants are large enough to deal with pests.

Except for birds.  By making little hoop greenhouses you can open the ends of the row for ventilation and still protect your onions, berries from birds. This tool is one of the cheapest and most versatile in the gardener's tool box.

Comment: Agree with Stormy's suggestion. If you had a smaller area, you could do hardware cloth cages, but for an area as large as you have, the cost would be high.